# Dropping file on a hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make a nicely looking drag&drop file input (without path string and upload button, but simply as an empty box with a border). To do this I used `visibility: hidden` property - this way the file input is indeed empty. I didn't use `display: none` because it seems to "remove" the element from the DOM.

The problem is that the `onDrop` event doesn't work in this case. `onClick` doesn't work either. I have to make the element visible to make it work, but then again, I don't want the content to be visible.

How could I deal with this?

Comment: Small thing to keep in mind (this will not solve the issue since you said that onClick doesn't work either, but it might prevent further issues): if you want onDrop to work, you will need to disable the default onDragOver event.

EDIT: this can be done with something along the lines of:
`document.ondragover = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opacity, it seems to do what you want:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Comment: I don't think that will work either, you have to put it to a very low opacity like 0.01

Answer (score 0):

How about moving it out of view with something like:

```
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 9999px;
```

Comment: If it's out of view, how will you drop something on it?

Comment: I have changed that to ```padding-top``` now. So the element is still there but the contents is out of view.